# How to translate "evaluate, estimate" [time for smt.]?

Tags: translation

There are lots of synonims in Chinese for "evaluate, estimate", so my question is: what is the best match for "evaluate/estimate time needed for something"

E.g.

> I want to estimate how long it will take me to prepare for examination.
>
> 我要 [评定] 准备好去应考需要多少时间。

---

**UPDATE (15.01.2018)**

Till now there are four answers and comments and all of them give different versions:

- @Diaph - **估计 or 评估** (我想要[评估]准备应考需要多少时间?)
- @user6065 - **计算、估算，琢磨**
- @Pedroski - **预测** (我想预测准备这场考试要多长时间。)
- @dan - **预估** (我想预估一下我要花多长时间来备考。)

So please provide some prove or explanation why this translation is used in your answer.

---

**UPDATE (some examples from internet; English translation is mine):**

**估计 [gūjì]** is mostly used as a noun:

- **时间估计**能准确一些 *(Time estimation could be more precise)*

But also:

- **估计**备份处理**时间** *(Estimate backup processing time)*
- 正在**估计时间** *(Estimating time...)*

Comment: 估计 or 评估. Try this: 我想要[评估]准备应考需要多少时间?

Comment: see online dictionaries,e. g. feed "estimate how" to iciba: find sample sentences with 计算、估算，琢磨，

Answer (score 1):

> I want to estimate how long it will take me to prepare for examination

In this case, I will use 预估. 
我想预估一下我要花多长时间来备考。 备考 is short for 准备考试.

Comment: `预估` +1. My manager also use  a single word `估`: “你`估`一下做完这些工作需要多长时间”. It works too.

Answer (score 1):

evaluate means to form an opinion of the amount, value or quality of sth after thinking about it carefully, in Chinese '评估'.

estimate means to form an idea of the cost, size, value etc. of sth, but without calculating it exactly, in Chinese '估计'.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I want to estimate how long it will take me to prepare for the examination.
我想预测准备这场考试要多长时间。